# PHP Syntax ${"{$type}_method"}

Tags: php

I've been reading an PHP5 book, and the author commonly used this syntax

```
${"{$something}_somethingelse"};
```

I have no idea what that means. Does it dynamically generate a variable name?

Someone help me out?

Comment: The top voted answer is correct; However, I will say that as a long time PHP developer I rarely use these, and most of the time I consider them a code smell.

Comment: I'll help you out - buy another book. Definitely code smell to use these "commonly"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a language feature called [**Variable variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Consider the following piece of code:

```
$a = 'hello';
```

This is pretty straight forward. It creates the variable `$a` and sets its value to `'hello'`.

Let's move on with:

```
$$a = 'world';
${$a} = 'world';
```

Basically, since `$a = 'hello'`, those two statement are the equivalent of doing:

```
$hello = 'world';
```

So the following:

```
echo "$a ${$a}";
```

Is the equivalent of doing:

```
echo "$a $hello";
```

---

## Braces `{ }`

The braces are used to prevent ambiguity problems from occurring. Consider the following:

```
$$a[1] = 'hello world';
```

Do you want to assign a variable named after the value of `$a[1]` or do you want to assign the index `1` of the variable named after `$a`?

For the first choice, you would write it as such:

```
${$a[1]} = 'hello world';
```

For the second choice:

```
${$a}[1] = 'hello world';
```

---

## Your example

Now, for your example.

Let's consider that:

```
$something = 'hello';
```

Using your example as such:

```
${"{$something}_somethingelse"} = 'php rocks';
```

Would essentially be equivalent of doing:

```
$hello_somethingelse = 'php rocks';
```

Comment: Please remember that variable variables are usually a bad idea since it is usually the job of arrays (or objects) to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

They are 'variable variables'.  See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 1):

That will replace the `{$something}` with the value of $something.

I think the inner curly braces are just for readability and to help when doing `$object->property` etc.

Because it seems to be also in a variable, that is called a variable variable.

For example,

```
$foo = 'bar';

$$foo = 7;

echo $bar;

// produces 7;
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind - I misunderstood the first time I read it.

Answer (score 1):

Brackets allow you to make more advanced variable names. It your Case if  $something was equal to test it would be:

```
${"test_somethingelse"};
```

Which is just an advanced variable name.

Here is an example.

```
$test = "test";
${"test_test"} = "test2";

echo $test; // prints test
echo ${"test_test"}; // prints test2
```

Using Variable Varaibles, as everyone else mentioned, you can create variables based on other variables. So in your case, he was making a variable based on $something's value

```
$something = "test";

${"{$something}_somethingelse"};

turns into

${"test_somethingelse"};
```